# UNIQUE columns with count using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table with the following columns

```
Id
Address
City
Date
maxSeat
StateId [Foreign key with table State with columns Id,Name]
```

I want to write a LINQ query to get the List of unique StateId and its count

For example

> State1 5 rows
>
> State2 3 rows
>
> State3 1 rows
>
> State4 5 rows

```
List<int> uniqStates = dbContext.conflocations.Select(item => item.StateId)
                                              .Distinct().ToList();
```

This returns unique list of stateId only. How can I get associated count as well along with State Name using LINQ?

Answer (score 6):

You need [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
var uniqStates = dbContext.conflocations.GroupBy(item => item.StateId)
                          .Select(x => new 
                                  {
                                      StateId = x.Key,
                                      Count = x.Count()
                                  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the `GroupBy` method:

```
var uniqStates = dbContext.conflocations.GroupBy(item => item.StateId).Select(g=>new {StateId=g.Key,Count=g.Count()}).ToList();
```

Or using query syntax, you can also do:

```
 var uniqStates= from conf in dbContext.conflocations
                 group conf by conf.StateId into g
                 select new {StateId=g.Key,
                             Count=g.Count()
                            };
```

Now to get the state's name, if you have a navigation property of type `State` in your `Conflocation` entity, then you can do something like this:

```
var uniqStates= from conf in dbContext.conflocations
                 group conf by conf.StateId into g
                 select new {StateId=g.Key,
                             Name=g.FirstOrDefault().State.Name
                             Count=g.Count()
                            };
```

### Update

If your `StateWiseVenues` class has the same property types of the anonymous type where this query is projecting the result, then you can do this:

```
var uniqStates= from conf in dbContext.conflocations
                group conf by conf.StateId into g
                select new StateWiseVenues {StateId=g.Key,
                                            Name=g.FirstOrDefault().State.Name
                                            Count=g.Count()
                                           }; 
 if(uniqStates !=null) 
 { 
   state_venues = uniqStates.ToList();
 }
```

Comment: I am getting one Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType error while trying to convert the uniqStates to a custom Model using the code  if(results !=null)
            {
                state_venues = (List<StateWiseVenues>)results;
            }

Comment: After this i am getting this exception
The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: Hi @JibinMathew, after using `FistOrDefault`, did you get the result you were expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to jint the two tables:

```
using( var dbContext=...)
{
   var results = from c in dbContext.conflocations
                 from s in dbContext.States.Where(x=>x.Id = c.StateId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 group new {c, s} by s.StateId into grp
                 select new { 
                              StateId = grp.Key,
                              StateName= grp.Max(x=>x.s.Name),
                              Count = grp.Count()
                            };
   ...
}
```

Comment: Whats key ?? I am getting build error key doesnot exists

Comment: It's the key of the group: `s.StateId` in this case